# ExchangeLinq: LINQ Query Provider for Stack Exchange API v2.0

Tags: library, api-v2, c#, .net, windows-phone

ExchangeLinq is a LINQ Query Provider for the Stack Exchange API. It only supports API v2.0. It is currently in **alpha** state and is being developed for Exchange It, a Stack Exchange client for Windows Phone.

ExchangeLinq doesn't do the OAuth process. You need to implement this yourself, for example by using a browser control.

It currently supports .NET 4, Silverlight 4 and 5 and WP7.1, and makes use of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) and [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

#### Sample code:

```
ISiteStackExchangeContext context = StackExchangeContext.Create(<apiKey>, <apiSiteParameter>);
IStackObservable<Question> questions = from q in context.Questions 
                                       select q;
questions.Subscribe(...);
```

The syntax is very intuitive and you get **full intellisense support** in visual studio.

#### Source

https://github.com/jlaanstra/ExchangeLINQ

#### License

Ms-PL

#### Platform

.NET 4, Silverlight 4 and 5 and WP7.1 (Portable Library coming soon)

#### Contact

Feel free to contact me via my [blog](http://blog.johanlaanstra.nl) or to contribute by opening pull requests on github.